# faultString: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I am trying to give web service call using Axis genrated stub.

It is running giving below exception when it tryies to get respons.

and when i view my response message using :

```
String responseMsg = stub._getCall().getMessageContext().getResponseMessage().getSOAPEnvelope().toString();
```

System.out.println(responseMsg);

it is giving the correct response in SOAP format. can anybody help me where it is creating issue thanks in Advance.

Zuned

```
   AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanPropertyTarget.set(BeanPropertyTarget.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.valueComplete(DeserializerImpl.java:249)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:509)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.hps.webservice.SOAPInterfaceBindingStub.getStatus(SOAPInterfaceBindingStub.java:852)
    at com.hps.ws.HPSStatusManagerJob.getApplicationStatusResponse(HPSStatusManagerJob.java:265)
    at com.hps.ws.HPSStatusManagerJob.updateStatus(HPSStatusManagerJob.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor.set(BeanPropertyDescriptor.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanPropertyTarget.set(BeanPropertyTarget.java:75)
    ... 22 more

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:admin-PC

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2470)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.hps.webservice.SOAPInterfaceBindingStub.getStatus(SOAPInterfaceBindingStub.java:852)
    at com.hps.ws.HPSStatusManagerJob.getApplicationStatusResponse(HPSStatusManagerJob.java:265)
    at com.hps.ws.HPSStatusManagerJob.updateStatus(HPSStatusManagerJob.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean$MethodInvokingJob.executeInternal(MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.java:264)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanPropertyTarget.set(BeanPropertyTarget.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.valueComplete(DeserializerImpl.java:249)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:509)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.replay(SAX2EventRecorder.java:171)
    at org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.publishToHandler(MessageElement.java:1141)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.deserialize(RPCElement.java:236)
    at org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement.getParams(RPCElement.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2467)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor.set(BeanPropertyDescriptor.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanPropertyTarget.set(BeanPropertyTarget.java:75)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you create the message and how it would look like - what properties, what types do they have, what is the method signature etc.?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. The problem is resolved . The error was due to DATA type difference of one field in WSDL and the wsdl genrated classes.

Comment: how did you solve this problem. Did you get new wsdl or you used some method to generate classes

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the local WSDL was not updated so I first updated the local WSDL and then genrated the classes once again .

:)

Answer (score 1):

one more way to generate file as in my case axis 1.4 was not working because of compatibility issue(not sure what it is). we can use wsimport.exe inbuilt in jdk to generate stub 
go to your jdk bin folder and run command  wsimport -s destinationPath WSDL path 
as:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>wsimport -s C:\sid\ http://?WSDL

after that copy paste generated folder structure and classes